# Drupal 7.12 Translate Custom Fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck

How do you translate custom fields in Drupal 7.12? I have came across the Entity Translation module though it also supports 7.15+ core,

Any ideas? greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I too have a same problem...and finaly got solution... PFB steps to fix it

1. Enable i18n's i18_field "Field translation" submodule
2. Go to admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string
3. Checked 'fields' (properly check all) and Click on "Refresh strings".
4. Go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate
5. Search desired string and translated it to other lang.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your Drupal core, you would be able to use that module. The current stable release in 7.x branch is 7.22. You should upgrade your core and other contributed modules to latest stable releases.